# Subject doesn't qualify for public certification SearXNG

Tags: networking, docker-compose, linode, tls1.3, searxng

I have been following a tutorial by NetworkChuck setting up SearXNG on Linode so i can "ditch Google". I have followed all the instructions and yet i keep getting this error:

[terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kf1Kr.png)

This in turn, stops the website from working. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

In `.env`, check the value of `SEARXNG_HOSTNAME` is a valid DNS name.

For reference:

- https://caddy.community/t/subject-name-does-not-qualify-for-certificate/10764/7
- https://github.com/caddyserver/caddy/issues/3977